# Child doesnt respect parent height

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make a vertical scroll on my `.left`  class.

When i try to instert `overflow-y: scroll`, nothing happens.
I tried to set `max-height` on parent container, but its exceeds the div limits
I tried to set also `overflow-y: scroll` on `.left` divider.

Here is a reproduction.

> Stackblitz:
> https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-49iyin?file=index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a scroller inside that element, you need to have a fixed height for that parent element

```
.content {
  height: 500px;
  background: #ddd;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.product-list {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 24px;
}

.left {
  height: 400px; /* Should have a fixed height here */
  overflow: auto; /* Should be auto instead of `scroll` */
  flex: 0.3;
  background: #6200ff70;
}

.product {
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 8px;
}
```

If you want to have a scroller for the entire area under `content`. You can set like this

```
.content {
  height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

Comment: I tried to make him fill in 100% of the parent, but he still doesn't respect parent height

Comment: the problem is your `.left` does not have a fixed height and the scroller relies on the current element itself. If you want it respect the parent's height, you can try this https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-x8ppjs?file=styles.css